# Querying a MySQL database to insert into a specific record

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I'm trying to insert data about a user on my website but I think the MySQL query I'm using is invalid. I want to insert the value '$profile' into the 'pph_user_bio' column inside the 'pph_user_profile' table however inside that table is a foreign key linking back to a table named 'users' which stores the user's '_id' so I only want the database to insert the data ($profile) into the corresponding '_id' which is set as the current session id.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (pph_user_profile) VALUES ($profile)" .
"SELECT _id " .
"FROM users" .
"WHERE _id = ". $_SESSION['_id_of_user'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I'm pretty new to MySQL so is there anyone who can tell me where I've made the error?

EDIT:

Here is an updated query, I'm still trying to do the same thing and no rows exist in 'pph_user_profile' so It's definitely insert.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (_id) VALUES " . $_SESSION['_id_of_user'];
mysql_query($query);                    

$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (pph_user_bio) VALUES ($bio) WHERE _id = " . $_SESSION['_id_of_user'];                                                                               
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: You need to change the second instance of "pph_user_profile" to "pph_user_bio" if you want to insert into that specific column. See my answer below for the full query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for an `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT`:

```
$query = "UPDATE pph_user_profile SET pph_user_profile=$profile" .
"WHERE _id = ". $_SESSION['_id_of_user'];
```

You use `UPDATE` to set the value on an existing record, and you can use a `WHERE` clause to specify which record to update.

To insert a new row, setting both columns, you can do this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (pph_user_profile, _id)".
"VALUES ($profile, ". $_SESSION['_id_of_user'] .")";
```

To insert a new row, but update it if the key already exists, use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (pph_user_profile, _id)".
"VALUES ($profile, ". $_SESSION['_id_of_user'] .")".
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pph_user_profile = $profile";
```

Comment: Currently there are no rows in the table so I still think it's insert, would you mind changing your example so it inserts please?

Answer (score 1):

Does the row in pph_user_profile already exist? If yes, you want to UPDATE instead of INSERT. If no, you'll need to insert both the data and the id of the user.

Your SQL is invalid because you're trying to run two different statements without separating them. If you were running the SQL directly on the server, you'd need to put a ; between them. Since you're doing it through PHP, you should limit yourself to one query per call to mysql_query()-- eg, make two calls, one for each query.

Edit

You're using

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (_id) VALUES " . $_SESSION['_id_of_user'];
mysql_query($query);                    

$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile (pph_user_bio) VALUES ($bio) WHERE _id = " .  $_SESSION['_id_of_user'];                                                                               
mysql_query($query);
```

Try:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pph_user_profile SET `_id` = '{$_SESSION['_id_of_user']}', `pph_user_bio` = '$bio'";
mysql_query($query) || die("Error inserting into pph_user_profile: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: I agree, I'll edit my code to show you my new query, although it still isn't working.